# Как удалить пробелы перед текстом

Tags: javascript

Нужно пройтись по массиву translates и удалить все пробелы перед началом текста или если в тесте одни пробелы то удалить их все и чтобы была просто пустая строка например чтобы вместо `{text: '   some text'}` было `{text: 'some text'}`. Я сделал вот таким способом но почему не работает `replace(/^\s+/g, "")` в чём может быть ошибка?

```js
const translates = [
   { text: '    some text' },
   { text: '           ' }
]


translates.forEach(item => {
   item.text = item.text.replace(/^\s+/g, "");
})

console.log(translates);
```

Comment: Как не работает? Работает. У меня по вашему примеру пробелы удалились. Попробуйте в консоли `"   s  ".replace(/^\s+/g, "")` -- все норм.

Comment: В полифилле такая же регулярка: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart#Polyfill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [`trimStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart):

```js
console.log('    some text'.trimStart());
console.log('           '.trimStart());
```

Comment: В IE не поддерживается https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart

Comment: @AlexDevTime, и что?

Comment: И то, что это не кроссбраузерно.

Comment: @AlexDevTime, это смотря какие браузеры указать

Answer (score 2):

Можешь воспользоавться методом [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```
 const translates = [
    { text: '    some text' },
    { text: '           ' }
];

translates.forEach(item => {
    item.text = item.text.trim();
});

translates.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.text);
})
```